# When JQuery triggers the displaying of a div, the file upload function within the div breaks in mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I have a little JQuery script that checks the image dimensions of a photo and if the photo is large enough, it shows the customization functions below (AKA the "form.cart" class).

Everything works fine in all browsers but for some reason in mobile Safari, the "UPLOAD" button stops working (still works in Chrome for iOS funnily enough). By not working I mean the options to select a file from your photo gallery doesn't work. If I turn off the script, it works so there's something going on but I'm not sure what.

My only guess at this point is that it has something to do with the DOM not properly loading but I have no idea why Chrome and Safari for iOS are affected differently as I thought they both used the same rendering engine.

https://victoryposters.com/product/need-for-speed/ (use any photo)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#filecheck").change(function() {
  var file, img;

  if ((file = this.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
      //hide customization if less than 1800 x 1800
      if (this.width < 1 && this.height < 1) {
        $('.pass').css('display', 'none');
  $('.fail').css('display', 'block');
  $('form.cart').css('display', 'none');
      }
      
   //show customization if over than 1800 x 1800
      else {
        $('.pass').css('display', 'block');
  $('.fail').css('display', 'none');
  $('form.cart').css('display', 'block');
      }
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
});

});
```

```css
form.cart {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="droparea">
<span class="ppom-dragdrop-text" style="margin-top:0px;">Before proceeding, check the quality of the image you intend on using</span>
<label for="filecheck" class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_0 vic_btn et_pb_bg_layout_light"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> CHECK PHOTO</label>
<input type="file" name="photo" id="filecheck" />

<div class="pass"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> Image quality good! Proceed to customisation.</div>
<div class="fail"><i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i> Image quality too low. Please select a different image.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Worked just now in Safari, but your snippet does not have JQuery

Comment: Did you test the UPLOAD button? The “CHECK PHOTO” button appears to be working fine